# How can I create a trigger to unpack json data?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, common-table-expression

This is the simplest reproducible example I can come up with. I would like to create a materialized view which is managed by triggers. This MV extracts some data from a json column, which could have an unbounded number of values in an array. Since we don't yet have `json_table` I am extracting these in a recursive CTE.

```
create or replace table base_data(
    id int auto_increment not null primary key,
    record_data longtext not null check (json_valid(record_data))
);

insert into base_data(record_data)
values
('{"x":1, "y":[2,3,4]}')
;

create or replace table mv_integers as
with recursive array_values as (
    select 
        json_extract(b.record_data, '$.y[*]') val
        , b.id
        , json_length(json_extract(b.record_data, '$.y[*]')) n
        from base_data b
), rec_elems as (
    select av.id, 0 as i, json_extract(av.val, '$[0]') elem
    from array_values av
    where av.n > 0
    union all
    select av.id, e.i + 1, json_extract(av.val, concat('$[', e.i + 1, ']'))
    from array_values av
        inner join rec_elems e on av.id = e.id
    where (i + 1) < av.n
)
select r.id record_id, r.elem extracted_integer, 'y' as 'comes_from'
from rec_elems r
union all
select b.id, json_value(b.record_data, '$.x'), 'x'
from base_data b
;

create or replace trigger maintain_mv_integers
after insert on base_data for each row 
insert mv_integers(record_id, extracted_integer, comes_from)
with recursive array_values as (
    select 
        json_extract(new.record_data, '$.y[*]') val
        , new.id
        , json_length(json_extract(new.record_data, '$.y[*]')) n
), rec_elems as (
    select av.id, 0 as i, json_extract(av.val, '$[0]') elem
    from array_values av
    where av.n > 0
    union all
    select av.id, e.i + 1, json_extract(av.val, concat('$[', e.i + 1, ']'))
    from array_values av
        inner join rec_elems e on av.id = e.id
    where (i + 1) < av.n
)
select r.id record_id, r.elem extracted_integer, 'y' as 'comes_from'
from rec_elems r
union all
select new.id, json_value(new.record_data, '$.x'), 'x'
;

insert into base_data(record_data)
values
('{"x":5, "y":[6,7,4]}')
;
```

What the code does:

1. Create a table
2. Populate that table with some data
3. Create a materialized view from that data
4. Create a trigger to maintain the materialized view going forward
5. Insert some new data to see if the trigger works

The code fails on the last step. The error is `Unknown column 'record_data' in 'NEW'`. If I comment out the bit before the `union all` and just leave the last bit which doesn't involve a CTE, then the code works. Does this mean that CTEs are not supported in triggers? I hope not and I can't find any documentation that supports this conclusion.

My version is `10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~bionic` running on WSL2 Ubuntu.

So how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a workaround. All I did was put the logic of the trigger into a stored procedure and call it from the trigger. That fact that this works and the original does not, suggests that this is either a bug or undocumented behavior.

UPDATE: this is now a [confirmed bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24488).

```
create or replace table base_data(
    id int auto_increment not null primary key,
    record_data longtext not null check (json_valid(record_data))
);

insert into base_data(record_data)
values
('{"x":1, "y":[2,3,4]}')
;

create or replace table mv_integers as
with recursive array_values as (
    select 
        json_extract(b.record_data, '$.y[*]') val
        , b.id
        , json_length(json_extract(b.record_data, '$.y[*]')) n
        from base_data b
), rec_elems as (
    select av.id, 0 as i, json_extract(av.val, '$[0]') elem
    from array_values av
    where av.n > 0
    union all
    select av.id, e.i + 1, json_extract(av.val, concat('$[', e.i + 1, ']'))
    from array_values av
        inner join rec_elems e on av.id = e.id
    where (i + 1) < av.n
)
select r.id record_id, r.elem extracted_integer, 'y' as 'comes_from'
from rec_elems r
union all
select b.id, json_value(b.record_data, '$.x'), 'x'
from base_data b
;

create or replace procedure sp_maintain_mv_integers(
    in record_id int unsigned,
    in json_data longtext 
)
insert mv_integers(record_id, extracted_integer, comes_from)
with recursive array_values as (
    select 
        json_extract(json_data, '$.y[*]') val
        , record_id id
        , json_length(json_extract(json_data, '$.y[*]')) n
), rec_elems as (
    select av.id, 0 as i, json_extract(av.val, '$[0]') elem
    from array_values av
    where av.n > 0
    union all
    select av.id, e.i + 1, json_extract(av.val, concat('$[', e.i + 1, ']'))
    from array_values av
        inner join rec_elems e on av.id = e.id
    where (i + 1) < av.n
)
select r.id record_id, r.elem extracted_integer, 'y' as 'comes_from'
from rec_elems r
union all
select record_id, json_value(json_data, '$.x'), 'x';


create or replace trigger tg_maintain_mv_integers
after insert on base_data for each row 
call sp_maintain_mv_integers(new.id, new.record_data);

insert into base_data(record_data)
values
('{"x":5, "y":[6,7,4]}')
;
```